# While running "sudo iotedge check --verbose" i am getting error

Tags: azure, azure-iot-edge

I have account on MS Azure. I am able to deploy docker images there, but while listing those deployed modules on my VM, I cannot see any container in terminal (`systemctl iotedge list`) I am using this command to list. And to check status of `iotedge` (`sudo iotedge check --verbose`) it is giving error:

[image]

Comment: did you follow this tutorial? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/quickstart-linux

Answer (score 0):

This means something is not allowing network access from within your container. It is usually DNS if deployed in a corporate environment and you might need to add a use an internal DNS Server. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/troubleshoot#edge-agent-module-continually-reports-empty-config-file-and-no-modules-start-on-the-device